# How to execute a <script> tag in a <a> element in html?

Tags: javascript, html

**Heres my code:**

```
<div>
   <a onclick="settings()">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js">
     <img src="icons/gear.png"
   </a>
</div>
```

I wanna keep the icon for the button

Comment: The question doesn’t make a lot of sense. [Validate your HTML](//html5.validator.nu/). Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and with [events](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/Events). Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: Instead of using a `script` tag inside of an `a` tag, can't you make the `a` tag a `button`, and in the JavaScript code, listen to a `click` event using `addEventListener`, and in there, add all of your code. **Also, don't add your `script` tag in the `a` tag!** Thanks!

Comment: Also, please explain what you are trying to do, instead of just giving us some code and one sentence to work with. These suggestions are just to make sure your question doesn't get **closed**.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an EventListener which will listen when someone clicks on the anchor tag (`<a></a>`).
So to do this, first let's give our anchor a class name, for this example:

```
<a class="example">Click Me</a>
```

Now, in our javascript file, we need to select this element by its class name. To do that we need to:

1. Define a variable (`myVariable`)
2. Select the anchor tag and assign it to that variable.

So:

```
var myVariable = document.querySelector('.example');
```

We created a variable and named it **myVariable**. We use **document.querySelector('.example')** to select our anchor element by its class name and assign it to our variable.

Now we need to create an EventListener:

```
myVariable.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // some code to be executed
})
```

Here you can see that we used the variable followed by a dot (.) and `addEventListener()`.

Q: Why did we use the variable name?
A: We use the variable name before `.addEventListener` because we actually want to "listen" when someone executes a specific event on our anchor tag, in this case the "click" event.

Note: You should never put  inside some div element.>ou always add them to the bottom of the page, before the closing `</body>` tag.

So it should look like this:

```
</body>
<!--Some Code-->

<script src="example.js"></script>
</body>
```